# Can't create design matrix from user input

Tags: r

I am trying to create a design matrix from user input

Data.csv:

```
X,Gender,Y
68,M,G1
74,M,G1
71,M,G1
71,M,G1

my_data <- read.csv("Data.csv")
var1   <-  "X"    'say it is user-input'
var1   <-  noquote(var1)
var1   <-  paste("my_data$", var1, sep="")
var1   <-  noquote(var1)
design <-  model.matrix(~0+var1, data=my_data)
```

The following error occurred

> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
>               contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

whereas

```
design <-  model.matrix(~0+my_data$X, data=my_data)
```

is working fine

Answer (score 2):

We can use `as.formula` to construct a `formula` to be used in `model.matrix` based on a user-specified predictor variable `var1`

```
var1 <- "X"
model.matrix(as.formula(sprintf("~ 0 + %s", var1)), data = df)
```

This gives the same design matrix as

```
model.matrix(~ 0 + X, data = df)
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.csv(text =
    "X,Gender,Y
68,M,G1
74,M,G1
71,M,G1
71,M,G1")
```